# What is this part of the code doing?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ssl, network-programming

I am new to c programming. As a part of my uni course for network security, I have to design a SSL handshake simulation. I found a sample code online, however i don't understand some parts of the code. Could you please help me with following :

What does `(char) 0` do ??  ( send_data is defined as `char send_data[1024];` )

```
send_data[0] = (char) 0;                //Packet Type = hello
send_data[1] = (char) 3;                //Version
```

**EDIT + FOLLOWUP**

Folks I know what type casting is.

I understand what casting is But the code I posted is doing nothing. Even though integer 0 is being cast as a character, its not doing anything because when you print it - its a blank - no value.

eg  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char test;
int num;

num = 1;
test = (char) num; // this does nothing

printf("num = %d , %c\n",num,num);
printf("test = %d , %c\n",test,test);

    // Isn't this the correct way to do it ?? :

num = 3;
test = '3'; // now this is a character 3

printf("num = %d , %c\n",num,num);
printf("test = %d , %c\n",test,test);

return 0;
```

}

the output of above code is :

```
num = 1 , 
test = 1 , 
num = 3 , 
test = 51 , 3
```

So why is it being done ?? isn't this the right way to do it :- send_data[0] = '0'; send_data[1] = '3';

Comment: ever heard of casting?

Comment: please read the "Programming in C" book by K&R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply casts the `int` 0 (or 3) into a `char` type.

It's possibly not necessary but may be used to remove warnings of possible truncation.

A better idiom would be:

```
send_data[0] = '\x00';   // Packet Type = hello
send_data[1] = '\x03';   // Version
```

since those are explicitly characters, without having to worry about casting.

Keep in mind that `(char) 0` (or `'\x00'`) is *not* the same as `'0'`. The former two give you the character code 0 (the `NUL` character in ASCII), the latter gives you the character code for the *printable* `0` character (character code 48 or `'\x30'` in ASCII). *That's* why your printing isn't acting as you seem to expect.

Whether your *particular* protocol requires code point 0 or printable character 0 is something you haven't made clear. If you're truly trying to emulate SSLv3, the correct values are the binary rather than printable ones as per [RFC6101](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101):

```
enum {
    hello_request(0), client_hello(1), server_hello(2),
    certificate(11), server_key_exchange (12),
    certificate_request(13), server_done(14),
    certificate_verify(15), client_key_exchange(16),
    finished(20), (255)
} HandshakeType;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just casting the literal symbol into a char value. But I don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is [casting](http://www.aui.ma/personal/~O.Iraqi/csc1401/casting.htm) the `int` value into the `char` type.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as `type-conversion` or `casting`. You do this when you need to change an entity of one data-type to another.

In your examples, 0 and 3 (integers) are being casted as type chars.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Answer (score 0):

`send_data` is defined as an array of `char`. But `0` and `3` are integer literals. When the integers are assigned to the array, they are being cast as `char`. This means that `send_data [0]` will hold the character with ASCII value 0, i.e. the `NUL` character. `send_data[1]` will hold the character with ASCII value 3, the `end of text` character.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() 
{ 
    char ch;
    ch = (char) 0;
    printf("%d\n", ch);   //This will print 0
    printf("%c\n", ch);   //This will print nothing (character whose value is 0 which is NUL)
    ch = (char) 3;
    printf("%d\n", ch);   //This will print 3
    printf("%c\n", ch);   //This will print a character whose value is 3
    return 0;
}
```

It is type casting int type to char type.

```
    Its good to create a demo program and test it when you get some doubts while reading.
```

Comment: s/This will print nothing/This will print a character whose value is 0/ - there's no difference between those code segments at all, both output exactly one char (either codepoint 0 or 3).

Comment: I understand what casting is

But the code I posted is doing nothing. Even though integer 0 is being cast as a character, its not accomplising anything because like in your example when you print it -  its a blank - no value. So why is it being done ??

isn't this the right way to do it :-

send_data[0] = '0';
send_data[1] = '3';